# livewallpaper force close on set

Tags: java, android, live, wallpaper

Could i get help with a live wallpaper ive been making in eclipse, I get several logcat errors. ive been working at it for a couple hours and dont know why i keep getting force closes. i get force closes on the "live wallpaper selection screen". i am not even able to view any live wallpapers when i run the application.
                    int x,y;

```
            public void onCreate()
            {
                    super.onCreate();
            }

            public void onDestroy()
            {
                    super.onDestroy();
            }

            public Engine onCreateEngine()
            {
                    return new MyWallpaperEngine();
            }

            class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine
            {

                    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            draw();
                        }
                    };
                    private boolean visible = true;
                    public Bitmap image1,backgroundImage;

                    MyWallpaperEngine()
                    {
                             // get the fish and background image references
                            image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fish);
                            backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.water);
                            x=-130; // initialize x position
                            y=200;  // initialize y position

                    }


                    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
                    {
                            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
                    {
                            this.visible = visible;
                            if (visible)
                            {
                                handler.post(drawRunner);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
                    {
                            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
                            this.visible = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                    }

                    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, 
                            float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels)
                    {
                            draw();
                    }

                    void draw()
                    {
                            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

                            Canvas c = null;
                            try
                            {
                                    c = holder.lockCanvas();
                                    // clear the canvas
                                    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    if (c != null)
                                    {
                                            // draw the background image
                                            c.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
                                            // draw the fish
                                            c.drawBitmap(image1, x,y, null);
                                            // get the width of canvas
                                            int width=c.getWidth();


                                            if(x>width+100)
                                            {  
                                                    // assign initial value to start with
                                                    x=-130;
                                            }
                                            // change the x position/value by 1 pixel
                                            x=x+1;
                                    }
                             }
                            finally
                            {
                                    if (c != null)
                                           holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }

                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                            if (visible)
                            {
                                      handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10);
                            }   

                    }
            }
```

Now Here is my Logcat

```
    12-05 09:29:28.893: I/ActivityManager(794): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GelWallpaperPickerActivity} from pid 1209
    12-05 09:29:28.954: I/ActivityManager(794): Start proc com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:wallpaper_chooser for activity com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GelWallpaperPickerActivity: pid=8101 uid=10022 gids={50022, 3003, 1028, 3002, 1015}
    12-05 09:29:29.054: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 1 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:3.800000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 60
    12-05 09:29:29.054: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:143.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.054: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:143.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.404: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 3 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 112
    12-05 09:29:29.404: E/MP-Decision(1580): DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 Ts:240 total_time_down:245.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.504: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 2 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:5.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 72
    12-05 09:29:29.504: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.504: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:92.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.524: D/dalvikvm(24807): null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping
    12-05 09:29:29.554: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 3 reqd : 4 available : 4 rq_depth:4.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 140
    12-05 09:29:29.554: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.554: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:0.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.554: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:3 core_idx:3 Nw:3.500000 Tw:90 total_time_up:138.000000
    12-05 09:29:29.644: I/Adreno200-EGL(8101): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
    12-05 09:29:29.744: D/OpenGLRenderer(8101): Enabling debug mode 0
    12-05 09:29:29.804: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 4 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:2.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 97
    12-05 09:29:29.804: E/MP-Decision(1580): DOWN cpu:3 core_idx:3 Ns:3.100000 Ts:240 total_time_down:241.000000
    12-05 09:29:30.065: I/ActivityManager(794): Displayed com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GelWallpaperPickerActivity: +1s118ms
    12-05 09:29:30.155: E/MP-Decision(1580): num online cores: 3 reqd : 4 available : 4 rq_depth:3.800000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 115
    12-05 09:29:30.155: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
    12-05 09:29:30.155: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:0.000000
    12-05 09:29:30.155: E/MP-Decision(1580): UP cpu:3 core_idx:3 Nw:3.500000 Tw:90 total_time_up:98.000000
    12-05 09:29:30.355: I/dalvikvm-heap(8101): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1085506396-byte allocation
    12-05 09:29:30.375: E/dalvikvm-heap(8101): Out of memory on a 1085506396-byte allocation.
    12-05 09:29:30.375: I/dalvikvm(8101): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=13 RUNNABLE
    12-05 09:29:30.375: I/dalvikvm(8101):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x423ac980 self=0x75ed44b0
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error "Out of memory on a 1085506396-byte allocation". Maybe you are getting this error due to low device memory or maybe the wallpaper size is too large.

Try to reduce the size of the live wallpaper or try to use a device (or emulator) with larger memory size.